# How to hide a code block/url for build with GruntJs?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I am using angular/yeoman and my service is using a different url in DEV then in PROD. How can I automate this with grunt running build? Also, is there a way to have two different "dist" folders created (to deploy for two different servers, again same app some blocks of code needed to be excluded in DEV, but slightly changed for build)

```
// Development only for testing 
var promise = $http.get('/fauxService/content.json')

// Build
var promise = $http.get('/realService/content.json')
```

Comment: I dont think there is a generator yet which lets you delete or add code-lines inside your JS-Files (i guess this would be what you are searching for). Why dont you just do it "the usual" way: Define a global Envorionment-Variable (maybe with an angular-constant) and wrap the url of that promise in a if-else condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [grunt-html-build](https://github.com/spatools/grunt-html-build) and create different sections in your index.html for dev, test, uat, production environment.

In your case, I would probably use a ["setting" service](https://github.com/williamverdolini/discitur-web/blob/master/app/modules/settings/SettingConfig.js) (where to put your constants to define your environment), with different versions depending on environment and choose the right configurations with specific grunt task (for example: https://github.com/williamverdolini/discitur-web/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L392)

it could be a way